# Scheme cons won't take two number arguments

Tags: list, scheme, racket, cons

I've seen many instances of cons taking two numbers as arguments, and I've been told to pass pass two numbers as arguments into cons in a lab, but whenever I do I get the following error:

```
> (cons 1 2)
cons: second argument must be a list, but received 1 and 2
```

If I do the following, I get the same error:

```
> (cons '1 '2)
cons: second argument must be a list, but received 1 and 2
```

I'm very new to Scheme, and I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: This is not Scheme behavior; suggest removing the Scheme tag as you've got it properly tagged as Racket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of the teaching language in use, it's probable that you're working with a student language with certain limitations. To solve the problem, make sure that this line is at the beginning of the file:

```
#lang racket
```

And choose the option "Determine language from source" in the bottom-left corner of DrRacket's window. Now this should work as expected:

```
(cons 1 2)
=> '(1 . 2)
```

Comment: As always, it's my pleasure ;)